# how to override implicitlywait() while doing try catch in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a framework where I have written `implicitlywait()` in superTESTNG class and all other sub class extends superTESTNG.
In many of my sub classes I have try catch.  The problem I am facing is due to this `implicitlywait()`.

The sub class  try catch is taking too much time to execute.  Please suggest a solution so that it will not wait during try catch.

This is my code:

in supertestNG

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

in subclass

```
try
{
    ProjectLibrary.SelectPreviousRecord(xlpath, sheetName, 2, 1);
}
catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
{
    ProjectLibrary.SelectPreviousRecord(xlpath, sheetName, 2, 2);
}

try
{
    ProjectLibrary.CompareStringTextByID(xlpath, sheetName, 2, 1, "Name","ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName");
}
catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
{
    ProjectLibrary.CompareStringTextByID(xlpath, sheetName, 2, 2, "Name", "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName");
}
```

Comment: I believe you'll have to use driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); in your subclass.

Comment: reset the time (1/2 secs) for implicitWait as soon as u enter in the try block in ur subclass. This way u can avoid wait...but make sure u define finally block to setback the time for implicitwait.

Comment: can u please provide the code to reset time to 1/2 secs when we enter try block in subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
{
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ProjectLibrary.SelectPreviousRecord(xlpath, sheetName, 2, 1);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
{
ProjectLibrary.SelectPreviousRecord(xlpath, sheetName, 2, 2);
}

try
{
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ProjectLibrary.CompareStringTextByID(xlpath, sheetName, 2, 1, "Name","ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
{
ProjectLibrary.CompareStringTextByID(xlpath, sheetName, 2, 2, "Name", "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName");
}
```